# How do you save a PDF from Selenium Driver in python?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

**python - 3.9.15**

**selenium -  4.7.0**

**firefox - 108.0.1 (64-bit)**

I'm developing a script that captures a static image of an online dashboard using selenium. I've tried...

```
driver.save_screenshot()
```

However, the image is too low in quality to share with our constituents. When I manually 'Save to PDF' and adjust the scale, paper size, and margin, I'm able to print out a functional and high resolution pdf.

I'm able to launch a print window with the following method and a print dialog box pops up. See image below.

```
driver.execute_script("window.print();")
```

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGChR.png)

However, I am unable to interact with the dialog box because the python console hangs on the execute_script method. I know how to send_keys to adjust the settings, but I cannot use these functions because I can't interact with the python console when the print dialog box is popped up.

Given the block below, I'm wondering if there are additional preferences available to set default print settings such as 'landscape', 50% scale, 1 inch margins, etc.  There are other settings to automatically 'Save to PDF' I believe. However, these settings alone will not adjust the orientation, scale, etc.

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", mime_types)
fp.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", mime_types)
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
fp.set_preference("dom.disable_beforeunload", True)
```

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: try ```driver.get_screenshot_as_png()``` and check the quality of the image.

Comment: if you want it as pdf use pypdf2 library

Comment: Thank you Gunesh. The print_page() method satisfies my pdf requirements. However, I don’t know how to alter the scale, orientation, etc of the export. That’s why I’m trying to utilize the print window.

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag

Comment: save_screenshot_as_png() worked for you ?

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag Does save_screenshot_as_png take a higher resolution PNG than save_screenshot()?

Answer (score 2):

The following returns a Base64 encoded Print Page as a string which can be converted into a PDF. I've used https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf to make the conversion.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.print_page_options import PrintOptions
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(...)

print_options = PrintOptions()
print_options.page_height = 8.5
print_options.page_width = 11
print_options.scale = 0.3

driver.print_page(print_options)
```

print_options is an optional parameter that can be passed into the print_page method. In theory, you can control the orientation, scale, background, page height & width, page ranges, and margins. However, I'm not sure how much control you really have on the layout. Maybe there is a reason this method doesn't have any resources to draw from.